# Avoid double input of items in an array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code which works

```
def add_item!(item, list)
  list << item
  list # this is what we return from the method
end
```

And if I had items to it it works.

```
add_item!(2, "henk")
add_item!(3, "george")
```

I however want to include a check whether the item is already in the list. I thought about doing this using the list.include? function. If I try this i get

```
def add_item! (item, list)

  if list.include?(item)
    list << item
    list
  else
    puts "This is a double item"
  end
end

add_item!(2, "list")
add_item!(2, "list")
```

This however gets me the following error:

```
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
```

I dont understand why this is happening and can avoid this. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure this does what you think it does - `list` is a String, not a list...

Comment: if you're just trying to get an array with no duplicate items..then you can just return the array as `list.uniq!`

Answer (score 3):

If you need a list, and you don't want duplicates, then don't use an Array, use a [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html):

> Set implements a collection of unordered values with no duplicates. This is a hybrid of Array's intuitive inter-operation facilities and Hash's fast lookup.

Instead of worrying about whether something already exists, you can keep your code looking like:

```
require 'set'
the_set = [].to_set

def add_item!(item, list)
  list << item
end

add_item!('foo', the_set)
the_set # => #<Set: {"foo"}>
add_item!('bar', the_set)
the_set # => #<Set: {"foo", "bar"}>
add_item!('foo', the_set)
the_set # => #<Set: {"foo", "bar"}>
```

If you need it to be an array, then use `to_a`:

```
the_set.to_a # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Really though, instead of creating a method that really doesn't reduce your code, simply use `<<`:

```
add_item!('foo', the_set)
the_set # => #<Set: {"foo"}>
the_set << 'bar'
the_set # => #<Set: {"foo", "bar"}>
```

It's shorter and will be faster than calling a method.

In my opinion, DRYing code by moving a single operation into a method doesn't really help and in the long run can make things worse because the action is hidden.

---

> I however want to include a check whether the item is already in the list. I thought about doing this using the list.include? function. If I try this i get

```
if list.include?(item)
```

Take a careful look at your conditional test. If `if list.include?(item)` means "item is in the list", do you want to append to the `list` variable?

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer. I understand that for the long term your solution would work. However Im doing some exercises which I need to pass using a list_include? function. Any solution ti this? Tried .to_s but that still gives me a syntax error

Comment: For exercises, you need to do as much of the work as possible, otherwise you won't be learning, you'll be having it handed to you. Researching by reading is one of our prime ways of learning how to program. I'd suggest looking at the [`Array#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) method's documentation as it explains how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with The Tin Man's answer - `Set` is the best way to maintain a unique collection. What concerns the exception being raised by your code - take a closer look at what you do:

```
add_item!(2, "henk")
```

You actually add an `Integer` to a `String`:

```
'henk' << 2
# => "henk\u0002"
```

In the second case

```
add_item!(2, "list")
```

you do exactly the same:

```
"list".include?(2)
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
```

So you should just pass an `Array` or `Set`  to your method instead of a `String`.

```
my_array = []
add_item!(2, my_array)
```

Also take a closer look at your `if`-statement

```
if list.include?(item)
  list << item
  list
else
  puts "This is a double item"
end
```

You are going to add an item to a list in case when it is already present there which obviously is not what you want to achieve, so you actually should either use `unless` instead of `if` or inverse it:

```
if list.include?(item)
  puts "This is a double item"
else
  list << item
  list
end
```

Also FYI with `Array` you can maintain it's uniqueness by doing

```
list |= [item]
```

eg.:

```
my_array = []
# => []
my_array |= [1]
# => [1]
my_array |= [1]
# => [1]
```